# How does If 1 = 2 = 3 Then (...) work

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

While coding in VB.NET i accidently wrote something like this into my code;

```
Dim a as integer = 1
Dim b as Integer = 2
Dim c as Integer = 3
If a = b = c Then
 '.. some Code
End if
```

It did not give me an error so it looks like it is a part of the programming language (or programming itself) that I do not know.

**My Question**:

How does this statement work and what are good examples for a use-case of this code?

---

**Edit**:

`Dim a as Integer = 1 = 2 = 3`

This line also does not give me an error. `MsgBox(a)` shows me a `0`

---

**The Answer**:

You can find it in the questions comments.

Comment: Change you project properties _Option Strict = ON_ and the error message will tell you the truth

Comment: the first "=" is affectation, the others are "comparison", and 4=5 gives 0 for example

Comment: it'd be running as `a == (b = c): compare b&c, assign boolean result (false) to a

Comment: @Steve `Strict` seems to be evil! I have a project with about 5000 lines of code.. it gave me hundreds of Compiling errors when saying `Integer a = Datarow.item("xy")`

But I get what strict does. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! I was about to understand it by Gar's comment ~ You confirmed my guess. So I guess writing code like a=b=c does work, but is nothing you should code like.. Am I right?

Comment: I'd call it a design abcess/wart. the same operator in two places in an expression having completely different semantics...

Comment: If you needed to do that I would recommend writing it as a = (b = c) for readability.

Comment: @Luke - it's not evil.  If you continue to code with it turned off, you will likely hit very difficult to find bugs.  Better to turn it on and leave it on and save yourself problems later.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway My point is, that I think it could make working with databses alot more time costly. When recieving information out of a database, I use datatables to read it. Then I go like myClass.myInt = row.item(xy) - This Item will always be an integer due to the fix database. Strict on sees the object -> integer conversion forcing me to use cint() making it more keystrokes than needed. Not sure I will use it, but it I will think about it.

Comment: Forcing you to be explicit about converting your database entries to ints is a good thing.  If you find yourself frustrated by extra typing, either A) You need to get over it; making your code readable is far more important than making your code easy to type or B) You need use some form of DAL so that each such conversion only happens once per column per semantic type.  If *typing* is slowing down your ability to write code, something is wrong.

Comment: As a less disruptive alternative, you could set Option Strict to Off for your database code and on for everything else.  If you need differing settings within the same class, [Scott Swigart Discusses how to resolve this on his blog](http://swigartconsulting.blogs.com/tech_blender/2005/03/granular_late_b.html) (short answer: use partial classes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, with `Option Strict Off` in effect (the default) that is a valid expression.  In that mode, VB.NET behaves (almost) like a dynamic language in the spirit of Javascript, Python or Ruby.  The compiler emits conversions where needed to make the expression valid, readily converting between strings, booleans and numeric types.

The expression is evaluated left-to-right, in other words (a = b) = c.  The a = b subexpression generates Boolean, it needs to be converted to Integer to make the comparison with c valid.  False produces 0, True produces -1.  Not a typo btw, part of the legacy when VB was still heavily based on COM automation.

The final expression type is Boolean again.  Note how your second statement requires that to be converted to Integer.  Since a = b with the given values always produces False, 0 = c will always be False.

With Option Strict On in effect, the compiler no longer applies these automatic conversions and generates an error on this statement.  It insists you use CInt() to convert the Boolean sub-expression.  Invariably good enough to discover that you fumbled the expression.

You probably ought to consider changing the default if mishaps like this byte frequently.  Use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VB Defaults > Option Strict setting.  Beware that it will be hard to ever switch back :)